# javascript coverage without unit tests

Tags: javascript, code-coverage

In a legacy webapp, we haven't any unit test on the javascript part.
We want to increase the code quality and delete dead code.
Is there any way to have line-by-line Javascript code coverage statistics in the browser during human test ? 
Is it possible to do that with istanbul for example ?

Answer (score 0):

Executing every use case in a single human testing session could be painful, I don't recommend this approach. There is a lot of automated integration test framework like http://casperjs.org or http://nightwatchjs.org with which you can code your test scenario in a close to human semantic.

Imo, automation is not a waist of time ;)

Comment: Ok, but unfortunately, we only have manual test books and don't have any time (money) to create automated integration test. 
We only want to increase code quality by remove dead code.

Comment: Build test scenario (automated or not) that will cover 100% of not dead code is very very hard, particularly if it is not automated. I suggest a console.warn approche to logs every function / class suspected to be dead.